# Desktop keeps hibernating, despite all sleep settings being disabled

Tags: sleep, hibernate

My desktop machine is a fairly simple build with a Gigabyte motherboard, a pair of NVME drives, a DVD R/W drive, and 64GB RAM.  Running Windows 10 and connected to a TrippLite UPS.

I typically power it down each night, but recently I've been running some long computer processes which require it to stay on for several days at a stretch.  On these occasions, I've observed is spontaneously hibernating in the middle of the day as long as I'm not touching the machine.  All sleep options are disabled, including the "hidden" one which requires a minor regedit to be able to access.

Parsing the Event Log shows clearly that the machine is entering a sleep state.  I checked it this morning to see when during overnight it went into this state, and found something else - a series of 6 "Power source changed" messages spanning about 7 minutes.

I've checked the logs for my UPS as well and they also show the machine going into a sleep state, specifically:

```
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] CommandInfo [ name='Get Discharging'; id=103; variation=5; protocolId=0x3016; className='Command_getdischarging_3016_com_hid_103'; priority='MEDIUM'; executionGroup='DATA'; commandType='GET'; communicationType='HID'; isIdle=false; isLiteral=false; isNullCommand=false; isCommandDataFormula=false; commandData=' 00 84 00 02 00 85 00 45 '; data=' '; inboundDataLength=1; outboundDataLength=8; line=0; dependsOnVariable=''; updatedVariables=('Battery Discharging','Battery Charge'); isAvailable=true; tag=;) ]
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] Sending 8 bytes to device: 00 84 00 02 00 85 00 45
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] Port '\\?\hid#vid_09ae&pid_3016#6&12b3d71&1&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}' Outbound to device: combined=0x84000200850045
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -5: [debug] Received message <<14>Sep 28 10:52:40 tradingPC CommandInfo [ name='Get Discharging'; id=103; variation=5; protocolId=0x3016; className='Command_getdischarging_3016_com_hid_103'; priority='MEDIUM'; executionGroup='DATA'; commandType='GET'; communicationType='HID'; isIdle=false; isLiteral=false; isNullCommand=false; isCommandDataFormula=false; commandData=' 00 84 00 02 00 85 00 45 '; data=' '; inboundDataLength=1; outboundDataLength=8; line=0; dependsOnVariable=''; updatedVariables=('Battery Discharging','Battery Charge'); isAvailable=true; tag=;) ]>
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -5: [debug] Received message <<14>Sep 28 10:52:40 tradingPC Sending 8 bytes to device: 00 84 00 02 00 85 00 45 >
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -5: [debug] Received message <<14>Sep 28 10:52:40 tradingPC Port '\\?\hid#vid_09ae&pid_3016#6&12b3d71&1&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}' Outbound to device: combined=0x84000200850045>
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] Port '\\?\hid#vid_09ae&pid_3016#6&12b3d71&1&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}' Inbound (four byte) from device: 00 00 00 00
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -5: [debug] Received message <<14>Sep 28 10:52:40 tradingPC Port '\\?\hid#vid_09ae&pid_3016#6&12b3d71&1&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}' Inbound (four byte) from device: 00 00 00 00 >

**2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] Handling entry to hibernation...**
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] Iterate over device 1
**2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -5: [debug] Received message <<14>Sep 28 10:52:40 tradingPC Handling entry to hibernation...>**
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -5: [debug] Received message <<14>Sep 28 10:52:40 tradingPC Iterate over device 1>
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] CommandInfo [ name='Stop Watchdog Timer'; id=239; variation=14; protocolId=0x3016; className='Command_stopwatchdogtimer_3016_com_hid_239'; priority='MEDIUM'; executionGroup='EXIT'; commandType='SET'; communicationType='HID'; isIdle=false; isLiteral=false; isNullCommand=false; isCommandDataFormula=false; commandData=' 00 84 00 20 ff ff 00 92 '; data=' 00 '; inboundDataLength=1; outboundDataLength=8; line=0; dependsOnVariable='Cmd Stop Watchdog Timer Data'; updatedVariables=(); isAvailable=true; tag=;) ]
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] Sending 8 bytes to device: 00 84 00 20 ff ff 00 92
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] Port '\\?\hid#vid_09ae&pid_3016#6&12b3d71&1&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}' Outbound to device: combined=0x00840020ffff0092; data=00
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -5: [debug] Received message <<14>Sep 28 10:52:40 tradingPC CommandInfo [ name='Stop Watchdog Timer'; id=239; variation=14; protocolId=0x3016; className='Command_stopwatchdogtimer_3016_com_hid_239'; priority='MEDIUM'; executionGroup='EXIT'; commandType='SET'; communicationType='HID'; isIdle=false; isLiteral=false; isNullCommand=false; isCommandDataFormula=false; commandData=' 00 84 00 20 ff ff 00 92 '; data=' 00 '; inboundDataLength=1; outboundDataLength=8; line=0; dependsOnVariable='Cmd Stop Watchdog Timer Data'; updatedVariables=(); isAvailable=true; tag=;) ]>
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -5: [debug] Received message <<14>Sep 28 10:52:40 tradingPC Sending 8 bytes to device: 00 84 00 20 ff ff 00 92 >
2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -5: [debug] Received message <<14>Sep 28 10:52:40 tradingPC Port '\\?\hid#vid_09ae&pid_3016#6&12b3d71&1&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}' Outbound to device: combined=0x00840020ffff0092; data=00 >
**2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] Handled entry to hibernation**
**2023-09-28T17:52:40Z tradingPC  - -5: [debug] Received message <<14>Sep 28 10:52:40 tradingPC Handled entry to hibernation>**
**2023-09-28T17:52:59Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] Handling exit from hibernation...**
**2023-09-28T17:52:59Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] Handled exit from hibernation**
2023-09-28T17:52:59Z tradingPC  - -1: [debug] set 'memoized_setups' on path 'CachingEntityRegistry((<Mapper at 0x197d3106550; SysLogServerModel>,))' to '{}'
2023-09-28T17:52:59Z tradingPC  - -1: [debug] Returning 1 devices
2023-09-28T17:52:59Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] updating active state for device 1. Updating active to false and initialized to false
2023-09-28T17:52:59Z tradingPC  - -1: [info] Device ID 1 is going inactive; clear Communication Lost Event = false
2023-09-28T17:52:59Z tradingPC  - -1: [debug] Clearing event active state and alarms only for device 1
2023-09-28T17:52:59Z tradingPC  - -1: [debug] successfully got the list of alarms.  Received 0 alarms
2023-09-28T17:52:59Z tradingPC  - -1: [debug] gRPC OK, in: (, <grpc._server._Context object at 0x00000197D3C)
**2023-09-28T17:52:59Z tradingPC  - -5: [debug] Received message <<14>Sep 28 10:52:59 tradingPC Handling exit from hibernation...>**
**2023-09-28T17:52:59Z tradingPC  - -5: [debug] Received message <<14>Sep 28 10:52:59 tradingPC Handled exit from hibernation>**
```

(I tried to bold the hibernation lines but that doesn't work in a code block... so consider the asterisks as the directly hibernation-related lines)

I've quit every background application, installed PowerToys and used the "Always Awake" option... nothing prevents this other than me physically moving the mouse around.  I'm at my wit's end as I need my machine to be able to run unattended for decent lengths of time.

Comment: Hibernation and Sleeping are two entirely different power independent modes. What hidden mode do you speak of exactly?

Comment: I would be inclined to update any drivers associated with power (even on a desktop) and BIOS (UEFI).  After final restart, pick your power plan, reset it to default, and then turn Hibernation OFF.  That should work. Test.

Comment: @Ramhound "System Unattended Sleep Timeout"

Comment: @John I'll check for BIOS updates, it's been a while since I've done that.  Everything Windows is always kept updated. Will report back any findings, thanks.

Comment: I myself use [Caffeine](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/) and it has never failed me.

Comment: "... connected to a TrippLite UPS."  Are you using the UPS USB connection and the TrippLite software that allows graceful shut down in event of low UPS battery? If you will be near machine to handle any power issue manually, try disconnecting that USB cord.

Comment: @DrMoishePippikYes, I already tried disconnecting it and it made no difference.  At the moment I have resorted to installing a ridiculous software utility which moves my mouse 1 pixel every 3 seconds.  It's doing a perfect job of preventing any sleep of any kind... but it's absurd that I would have to do this.  =/

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Interesting, I'm familiar with Caffeine for Mac but didn't know it was on Windows.  I'll give that a shot as well, thanks!

Comment: Well, even my mouse-moving software eventually failed to prevent the hibernation.  So I tried Caffeine at the suggestions of @SeñorCMasMas and sure enough, it's working perfectly.  Without it hibernation kicks in within 20 minutes, now I've had the machine running for hours without a hitch.  Still annoyed to need this solution, but at least I have it!

Comment: Even Caffeine eventually failed... but this led me to realize what the issue actually was.  I've provided my own answer below.  Thanks to all who chimed in with ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe what the solution turned out to be, so in case this same obscure set of circumstances happens to anyone else, here is the ultimate answer in this case.

After even software to move the mouse randomly at intervals, as well as the software `Caffeine`, couldn't keep the machine awake overnight... I was completely out of ideas.  Then this morning I had a fragment of a memory from long ago.

I looked in Task Scheduler, and sure enough... there at 11 PM was scheduled `Sleep`.  It was set to turn on only after an idle period of 10 minutes, AND to resume if interrupted.

I vaguely remember putting this in place years ago.  The combination of not starting until 11pm, the required 10 minute idle time, plus resuming if interrupted, made it just random enough to make no sense and not be an obviously scheduled thing.  Now that I've disabled that event... no more spontaneous hibernation!